# How to add appenders and loggers progtamatically

Tags: logging, logback

I have a `logback.xml` and it has some appenders and loggers in it. I want to add loggers and appenders programatically.

How will I be able to modify them in `logback.xml` ? 
Should I be doing it inside the config file somewhere?

I am very new to this and I have very little idea about how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it

```
  val MyLogger = LoggerFactor.getLogger("logger name") 
  MyLogger.setLevel(LEVEL.INFO)
```